# Add icon and buttons to Visualforce Page header in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning, page-layout

I added custom VF page to Account layout page. It shows 'label' for my VF page in header. Can I change this default header (circled in red on screenshot) somehow? I want to add icon and buttons. 
Or maybe I can just remove it and add custom header in VF page?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out only later, that it is better to build Lightning components instead of Visualforce Pages. In Lightning components it is possible to get rid of standard header.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the label from the page layout by clicking the wrench icon for the Visualforce page, and unchecking "Show label."

[image: Visualforce Page Properties Show label checkbox]

As you surmised, you will then need to modify your Visualforce page to show whatever additional elements you wish at the top.

Comment: You mean standard page layout. But how I can change it in Lightning page layout? I can't find there a wrench icon.

Comment: @klnkt Visualforce pages added via Lightning App Builder have to have a label. You can add Visualforce pages to the classic layout, which will cause it to appear in the Details component of the layout, and that one you can hide the label for. If you don't provide a value, you still end up with a default value.